# Is there a function to indirectly get a variable's value?

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, variables

I have a long script which I want to recreate as a loop. I'm running into an issue concerning one of my variables. Via the loop I want to recreate the variable name and get its value, which has already been inserted earlier on in the script.

The variable in question is **EngineeringEndDate**. Via the loop I can get name of this variable loaded into **ActivityNameEndDate**. Is there are way to get to the value of **EngineeringEndDate** in my loop?

Here is the script:

```
EngineeringEndDate = 01-01-2020
PurchaseEndDate = 01-02-2020
<Etc.>

For S = 115 To 128

    RoutingID = Settings.Range("A" & S).Value
    ActivityNameEndDate = Settings.Range("B" & S).Value & "EndDate"

    ActivityEndDate = DateValue(Format(<<EngineeringEndDate>>, "dd-mm-yyyy"))

Next S
```

gfdg

Comment: `ActivityEndDate = DateValue(Format(EngineeringEndDate, "dd-mm-yyyy"))`  << that will use the value as the name is just a label associated with the value.

Comment: This is how my script currently looks. But what I would like for this loop to do is insert EngineeringEndDate and then afterwards PurchaseEndDate, etc. In total there are 49 activities that need to go through the loop. Currently I have the same script 49 times

Comment: insert where please? What isn't working with code as written?

Comment: Inserting the value of the various activities within the loop, one at a time. E.g. S = 115 leads to ActivityNameEndDate = "EngineeringEndDate". But S = 116 leads to ActivityNameEndDate = "PurchaseEndDate". I would like to get the corresponding date within the loop.

Comment: Its up on the leaderboard as one of the more confusing questions asked so far in 2021.

Comment: Well, in short; I am recreating my variables as string but and I am unable to get the value assigned to that variable within the loop.

Comment: If you're asking what I think you're asking, you can't do it. You can't use cell contents to define a string which represents a variable. Use an array,

Comment: Alright, so how would that array look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array - and reduce your code:

```vb
Dim EngineeringEndDate As Date
Dim PurchaseEndDate As Date
' ...
Dim InvoiceDate As Date

Dim Dates(115 To 128) As Date

EngineeringEndDate = #01/01/2020#
PurchaseEndDate = #02/01/2020#
' ...
InvoiceDate = #02/15/2020#

Dates(115) = EngineeringEndDate
Dates(116) = PurchaseEndDate
' ...
Dates(128) = InvoiceDate


For S = LBound(Dates) To UBound(Dates)

    RoutingID = Settings.Range("A" & S).Value
    ActivityNameEndDate = Settings.Range("B" & S).Value & "EndDate"
    ActivityEndDate = Dates(S)

Next S
```